# Matlab-style C# chart ploting framework

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm coding a C# windows forms application (Visual Studio 2015) than needs to plot an oscillogramm. In this application I'm using standard Chart element but standard functions of this element is not enough for me: I need zoom and cursor mesurments like in Matlab Plot tool.

Do you know any solutions that I can integrate in my application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a decent use case for using MATLAB itself. With the MATLAB Compiler SDK, you can build a .NET assembly that you could then integrate into your .NET application. Or, if this plot is the sole functionality of your program, you could abandon C# altogether and compile an executable using MATLAB Compiler (mcc). I believe both solutions require the installation of an additional program (MATLAB Compiler Runtime), but otherwise the major downside of this approach would be abandoning the elegance of C# for the clunkiness of MATLAB code.

Comment: Hello! May you provide me a link to example of using Matlab functions in .NET application? At this moment I don't understand how to Integrate "Figure" from matlab to standard C# "Form". Thank you!

Comment: Sure, here's the MATLAB documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-dotnet-application-with-matlab-code.html

Comment: Ok I tried it. But I see that I have not the opportunity to integrate Matlab "figure" in my "form", so I have two different windows: my app and Matlab figure. It's unacceptable for me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer on my question: framework [Live Charts](https://lvcharts.net/) is a best solution for me.